# Magento - Get specific custom product option value

Tags: xml, product

I'm trying to make a custom XML feed for Magento. Everything's fine and dandy, however I've hit a roadblock. I'm trying to get specific custom product options for my products, but the method I'm using only dumps all product options.

How can I split these?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');

include '../app/Mage.php';
include 'ArrayXml.php';

Mage::app();

$_result   = array();
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSort('order', 'DESC')->addAttributeToSelect(array(
    'name',
    '*',
    'short_description',
    'description',
    'image',
    'media',
    'special_price',
    'special_from_date',
    'special_to_date',
    'current_category',
    'SKU',
    'id'
))->addPriceData();

foreach ($_products as $_product) {

    $productSku = $_product->getSku();
    $productId  = $_product->getIdBySku($productSku);

    $_product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($productId);
    $attVal   = $_product->getOptions();

    $optStr = "";

    // loop through the options
    foreach ($attVal as $optionKey => $optionVal) {

        $optStr .= $optionVal->getTitle() . ": ";

        foreach ($optionVal->getValues() as $valuesKey => $valuesVal) {

            $optStr .= " " . $valuesVal->getTitle();
        }
    }

    $arr         = Array();
    $catarr      = Array();
    $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();

    foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
        $catarr[] = $category->getName();
    }
    $_gallery = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();
    foreach ($_gallery as $_image) {
        $arr[] = "http://fancycouture.ro/media/catalog/product" . $_image->getFile();
    }
    $_result['product'][] = array(
        //'manufacturer' => 'Fancy',
        //'name' => $_product->getName(),
        //'categories' => array('category' => $catarr),
        //'product_code' => $_product->getSku(),
        //'price' => $_product->getFinalPrice(),
        //'bucati_disponibile' => '',
        //'description' => $_product->getDescription(),
        //'images' => array('image' => $arr),
        'dimensions' => $optStr
        /*'url_produs' => $_product->getProductUrl(),*/
    );
}
$_converter = new ArrayXML();
echo $_converter->toXML($_result);
?>
```

The output can be seen [here](http://fancycouture.ro/SATC/index.php)

Answer (score 2):

To get an attribute value: `$product->getAttributeText('attribute_name');`